# Formal definition of a functor in $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: category-theory, foundations

Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be categories. The first thing that comes to mind when considering a definition of a functor between $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is that it can be an ordered pair $(f\colon Ob(\mathcal{C})\to Ob(\mathcal{D}), g\colon Mor(\mathcal{C})\to Mor(\mathcal{D}))$ satisfying the functoriality axioms.

However, it can create a problems when considering a category of all categories (say, of all $U$-categories for a given universe $U$). $Hom(\mathcal{C}_1,\mathcal{D}_1)$ and $Hom(\mathcal{C}_2,\mathcal{D}_2)$ have to be disjoint unless $\mathcal{C}_1 = \mathcal{C}_2$ and $\mathcal{D}_1 = \mathcal{D}_2$. But a functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is essentially the same thing as a functor $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathcal{D}^{op}$ and a category is generally not equal to its opposite category.

So, do we need to define a functor between categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ as a $4$-tuple $(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D},f\colon Ob(\mathcal{C})\to Ob(\mathcal{D}), g\colon Mor(\mathcal{C})\to Mor(\mathcal{D}))$ for the formal definition to work in $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Comment: In these definitions, you can dispense with the objects, as they are recoverable from the morphisms.

Comment: This is a standard method, not only in category theory, but with functions and relations in general. We sometimes identify a function $X \to Y$ with its graph $G$ and sometimes with the triple $(X,Y,G)$, depending on whether we want to view the domain and codomain as intrinsic properties of the function.

Comment: An issue here is your definition of "category". For *small* categories, what you've said is reasonable enough. For locally small (or larger) categories, such as $\mathbf{Set}$, you need to be a lot more careful. $\mathsf{Ob}(\mathcal C)$ and $\mathsf{Mor}(\mathcal C)$ are potentially proper classes in these cases and so it doesn't (naively) make sense to talk about "functions" between them or having them as components of ordered pairs. Most of this is tedious technicalities though, and is often avoided by using Grothendieck universes a la Tarski-Grothendieck set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the definition of a functor as a quadruplet is standard (as a definition of a function between sets as a triplet). This approach does not lead to difficulties you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, Oskar. But what about natural transformations? Given two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, there is a category of functors between them, where morphisms are natural transformations. Is a natural transformation between functors $F$ and $G$ not only a family $(\alpha_X)_{X \in \mathcal{C}}$ of morphisms $\alpha_X\colon F(X)\to G(X)$ so that the naturality condition holds, but a triple $(F,G,(\alpha_X)_{X \in \mathcal{C}})$?

Comment: Yes, a natural transformation is a triplet (like a function). This does not provide any difficulties with size-issues, in view of my previous answer. And this is a general method to construct morphisms in the framework of the set theory: for instance, a group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a triplet $(G,H,f)$ (with extra properties).